Is the "AcceptMultipleTransactions" function in src/validation.cpp deprecated?
I am interested in how transactions are transmitted, processed, evaluated and finally being accepted. I was reading the source code and noticed that there are "AcceptSingleTransaction" and "AcceptMultipleTransactions" functions.
The latter is called only in "AcceptPackage" and "ProcessNewPackage" functions but it seems that that is where the chain of events end. The "ProcessNewPackage" function is used only for JSON RPC mempool acceptance testing and Regtest. I don't think this function is used for Bitcoin mainnet.
Q1 => Do every single transactions in Bitcoin mainnet go through "ProcessTransaction" -> "AcceptToMemoryPool" -> "AcceptSingleTransaction"?
Q2 => If the answer for Q1 is yes, then isn't it kind of inefficient? Is "AcceptMultipleTransactions" deprecated?
